# Compiling OpenCV for Visual C++ 9.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, compilation

I looked at many places but could not find anything telling me how to buld the lib files. I know how to link them, but openCV install folder only contains .a files. I cant find an sln file or dsp. How can I make the lib files? Right now all the samples get linker problems because the lib files dont exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows installer (.exe) for OpenCV 2.0 does not come with the binaries pre-built for vc++, nor does it have the .vcproj files for using vc++ to build them.  You need to have cmake, which is available for free on the web.  I used the GUI.  Use that to build .vcproj files with which you can compile everything in VC++ 2008 or whatever. **There are some gotchas.**  [The question has been asked and answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179222/how-to-install-opencv-2-0-on-win32)

Answer (score 0):

.a files are libraries.  On a unix platform they're typically statically linked libraries.

If you're on windows however they should be .dll files.  How did you compile OpenCV and does it support compiling on windows?

Comment: its supposed to work with it, but I only found this: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++
I did not compile it though, thats what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the .sln files you need to run [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) on the OpenCV folder containing makefiles.