# Compiling OpenCV

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, compilation

I opened up the solution file in the [InstallDir]\_make\opencv.vs2005 and modified one of the .cpp files in the highgui library.

While compiling, Visual Studio throws the error -

```
  Unable to start progam 
    C:/Users/../AppData/Local/Temp/opencv.build/cv_Debug.Win32/cv.dll

    The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I think I am missing something in it. What is the stepped procedure to change and recompile OpenCV library using Visual Studio.

I would appreciate any help!

Thank You..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164276/compiling-opencv-for-visual-c-9-0/2204671#2204671

Comment: I you should be very caution about changing opencv internal library,
opencv has many internal dependencies. unless it's something simple , I suggest using opencv as a "black box"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you downloaded the visual-studio specific version of the open cv distribution files, you need to follow the [instructions](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide#Build) on the [OpenCV wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome), that is

1. download [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/)
2. have cmake generate makefiles/solutions
3. build using the generated files

Comment: Hi, can you point me to the link for downloading the source-code of OPenCV? All I could find was an executable which does not contain any source code. Please help. I am new to all this! Thanks

Comment: The OpenCV wiki above has links to the OpenCV packages, right now the latest versions are at http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to customize a function. You can do this, without recompiling OpenCV from scratch. You can simply copy the .cpp source file locally in your current working directory, and add it(click n drag or add existing file) in the "Source Files" in your project. You might need to copy some other headers as well. You will find everything in the opencv archive. (opencv/modules/highgui/src)